# Non-Boost asio error in one app but not another

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio

I have a very simple asio TCP server:

```
using asio::ip::tcp;

class Client
{
public:
    Client(tcp::socket&& openedSocket)  : socket(std::move(openedSocket)), readBuffer(1024)
    {
        socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(readBuffer.data(), readBuffer.size()), std::bind(&Client::handleRead, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    }

private:
    void handleRead(const asio::error_code& error, size_t numRead)
    {
        if(error)
        {
            std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Reading" << std::endl;
        }
    
        socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(readBuffer.data(), readBuffer.size()), std::bind(&Client::handleRead, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    tcp::socket socket;
    std::vector<uint8_t> readBuffer;
};

class Server
{
public:
    Server()  : acceptor(context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 3030))
    {
        try
        {
            startAccept();
            context.run();
        }
        catch(const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    void startAccept()
    {
        acceptor.async_accept(std::bind(&Server::handleAccept, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void handleAccept(const asio::error_code& error, tcp::socket socket)
    {
        if(!error)
        {
            clients.push_back(std::make_unique<Client>(std::move(socket)));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
    
        startAccept();
    }

    asio::io_context context;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Client>> clients;
};
```

This code works with successful reads from a basic main function which does nothing but instantiate the Server.

However, when I run this code in a [JUCE](https://juce.com/) app, instantiating the Server from the JUCE message thread, connection to a client is successful but all reads cause the error 'bad file descriptor.'

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell because we don't see the code.

I've never used JUCE before, but here's my first ever take, using a basic GUI application that includes your code. The only change I made was allow the server to run in the background using `thread_pool` as the context.

```
#include <asio.hpp>
namespace SO {
using namespace std::placeholders;
using asio::ip::tcp;

class Client {
public:
  Client(tcp::socket &&openedSocket)
      : socket(std::move(openedSocket)), readBuffer(1024) {
    startRead();
  }

private:
  void startRead() {
    socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(readBuffer),
                           bind(&Client::handleRead, this, _1, _2));
  }
  void handleRead(const asio::error_code &error, size_t numRead) {
    std::cout << "Reading (" << error.message() << ", " << numRead << ")"
              << std::endl;

    if (!error)
      startRead();
  }

  tcp::socket socket;
  std::vector<uint8_t> readBuffer;
};

class Server {
public:
  Server() : acceptor(context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 3030)) {
    startAccept();
  }

  ~Server() {
    post(context, [this] {
      acceptor.cancel();
      acceptor.close();
    });
  }

private:
  void startAccept() {
    acceptor.async_accept(make_strand(context),
                          bind(&Server::handleAccept, this, _1, _2));
  }

  void handleAccept(const asio::error_code &error, tcp::socket socket) {
    if (!error) {
      clients.push_back(std::make_unique<Client>(std::move(socket)));
      startAccept();
    } else {
      std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }

  asio::thread_pool context;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor;

  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Client>> clients;
};
} // namespace SO

//==============================================================================
class sehejuceApplication  : public juce::JUCEApplication
{
    std::shared_ptr<SO::Server> soTcpServer;
public:
    //==============================================================================
    sehejuceApplication() {}

    const juce::String getApplicationName() override       { return ProjectInfo::projectName; }
    const juce::String getApplicationVersion() override    { return ProjectInfo::versionString; }
    bool moreThanOneInstanceAllowed() override             { return true; }

    //==============================================================================
    void initialise (const juce::String& commandLine) override
    {
        // This method is where you should put your application's initialisation code..

        mainWindow.reset (new MainWindow (getApplicationName()));
        soTcpServer = std::make_shared<SO::Server>();
    }

    void shutdown() override
    {
        // Add your application's shutdown code here..

        mainWindow = nullptr; // (deletes our window)
        soTcpServer.reset();
    }

// rest unmodified as autogenerated by Projucer
```

Live Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, the problem is not really the threading. I was trying to keep it as simple as possible by letting the context run on the juce message thread. The issue still occurs with the code you've provided. The odd thing is that connection and sending data through the client works find. Receiving data however consistently causes the problem I have mentioned above

Comment: If you can share the code you actually use we can help